# imagecreatefromstring can get url or file?

Tags: php, gd

I have an image with this src attribute http://myhost.lan/images/log/parts/bg/001.png can i pass this url to `imagecreatefromstring` function as a string? what's the exactly mean of 
`imagecreatefromstring — Create a new image from the image stream in the string` in imagecreatefromstring manual?

Answer (score 2):

yes, you could do:

```
$src = "http://myhost.lan/images/log/parts/bg/001.png";
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($src));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the image you are trying to load a is a type of `.png` image, you can do this instead:

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = imagecreatefrompng('http://myhost.lan/images/log/parts/bg/001.png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
exit();
```

Read the manual:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

Comment: I want to know what is the exactly mean of image stream??